# Android Chat Application using PHP server

Tags: php, android, server, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop a chat application just for two clients on different devices. Do I have to use Google Cloud Messaging? I want to use PHP server. 
As I have only two clients no database or login phase is needed I think.

How to set up the server so that clients can communicate with one another?

Answer (score 3):

You can go for XMPP chat implementation in Android.

http://vidorsolutions.blogspot.in/2011/01/writing-xmppjabber-chat-application-for.html

https://github.com/wihoho/Android-XMPP

you can visit above links. Hope it may help.

Comment: I am looking for the server side implementation ? Any suggestion about how i do it ? Do i have to use GCM . Can i implement GCM on php server ?

Comment: I am Android developer but I have done projects like this so Yes you can.